# Работает ли продвижение по позициям?

Tags: оптимизация, seo, поисковые-системы, продвижение

Хочу понять работает ли сейчас продвижение по позициям. Слышал, что оно утратило актуальность, хотя бы потому что для разных пользователей в зависимости от их поведения будут показываться разные позиции одного и того же сайта. Например на одном компьютере это будет третье место, на другом 27. А на третьем 127 и т.д. Причем смотрел на сайтах крупных сео компаний - почти все предлагают продвижение в т.ч. по позициям. Но как тогда они считают позицию, если на разных компьютерах она разная?

Comment: почему минусы-то ставят? вопрос очень понятный и конкретный. если сами не понимаете, можете просто не отвечать

Comment: предположу что вопрос слишком общий и не по тематике сайта. здесь сообщество программистов. Для веб мастеров есть этот сайт - http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ - он на английском.

Comment: Правильный он будет, если вы опишите например, сделал что-то, получил результат, как можно его скорректировать? А ваш вопрос лучше направить сюда - https://yandex.ru/support/webmaster/for-webmasters/contents.xml

Comment: что за бред, вопрос вообще-то про персонализацию результатов

Answer (score 0):

Нет, не утратило.

Да, позиции сейчас могут частично вариироваться в связи с поведением пользователя и его предпочтениям, местоположению и прочему. Но если вы в чистой выдаче (просмотр через режим инкогнито в необходимом регионе) находитесь на первых 3-х позициях, то Вас могут сместить в конец страницы предпочтениями пользователя. Но если пользователь только начал интересоваться темой, то вполне вероятно, что вы покажетесь на своей позиции.

К примеру, национальный новостной сайт по запросу "новости" имеет чистую первую позицию, т.к. пишет о всей стране, но пользователь Вася предпочитает читать региональный новостной сайт. Поэтому Васе по запросу "новости" региональный сайт покажется на первой позиции, а национальный - на второй. А Петя новостей не читает, поэтому по запросу новости ему показывает национальный сайт

Но это далеко не аксиома. Васе скорее всего все равно покажут первым национальный сайт - дофига новостей по все регионам, а региональный - где-то в конце первой страницы.

На одном факторе ранжирования выдача не строится. (Человек может переехать, сайт может быть заражен вирусом или взломан, протоколы защиты данных, настройки и прочая куча нюансов)

Comment: даже с чистыми режимами все равно прыгает выдача

Comment: и прикол в том, что юзеры -то в основном просто открывают поисковик и вводят запрос (т.е. в основной массе это не чистые инкогникто и прочее, а самый обычный с историей пользовательский запрос) и в основной массе в плане сео у всех получаются будут совершенно разные позиции

Comment: То, что прыгает в чистой - это на жаргоне "лестничная выдача" - в течении дня может менятся до +/- 5 позиций.
Да, но не катастрофически. Повторюсь - повлияет на 1-2 ресурса, но остальные как имели свои позиции, так и будут иметь +/-